# LinkedIn creative ad with an image and a call-to-action

Tags: linkedin-api

Using LinkedIn APIs I'm trying to create a Creative Ad with an image and a call-to-action button like the following example from campaignmanager:

[image: LinkedIn image ad]

I tried many possibilities using Asset and Share APIs to create a dark Share but i'm unable to create a Creative with an image and a call-to-action button. The [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#direct-sponsored-content-share) doesn't say if I should use `ARTICLE` or `RICH` `shareMediaCategory`. Setting `landingPageUrl` like in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#sample-object-including-image-assets) seems to have no effect when using from a Creative Ad.

I successfully created a video Creative Ad with a call-to-action but the new UgcPost API is only supporting `AdDirectSponsoredContent` for video.

Does somebody know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by creating first a `RICH` dark share that accepts an uploaded asset urn in the `entity` field:

POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares

```
{
  "owner": "urn:li:organization:1234",
  "agent": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:5678",
  "subject": "An ad title",
  "text": {
    "text": "An ad title"
  },
  "content": {
    "contentEntities": [
      {
        "entity": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ABCD",
        "entityLocation": "https://stackoverflow.com"
      }
    ],
    "shareMediaCategory": "RICH"
  },
  "distribution": {
    "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
  }
}
```

Then I create a 2nd `ARTICLE` dark share with the `thumbnails` info recovered from the 1st dark share plus the "call to action" button:

POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares

```
{
  "owner": "urn:li:organization:1234",
  "agent": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:5678",
  "subject": "An ad title",
  "text": {
    "text": "An ad title"
  },
  "content": {
    "contentEntities": [
      {
        "entityLocation": "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "thumbnails": [
          {
            "resolvedUrl": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/ABCD/feedshare-shrink_1280/..."
          }
        ],
        "title": "Click here to learn more!",
        "landingPageUrl": "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "landingPageTitle": "LEARN_MORE"
      }
    ],
    "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE"
  },
  "distribution": {
    "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you determine the `resolvedUrl` field for your thumbnail?